# Текст загрузки в Pascal

Tags: pascal

Как сделать прогресс "загрузки" в Pascal? От 1% до 100% за определенный промежуток времени. То есть за это время 1% сменяется на 2% и так до 100.

Comment: Использовать `timer`, который через заданный промежуток времени будет менять значение `progress bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший пример в `Lazarus`

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Задаем интервал в полсекунды
  Timer1.Interval:= 500;
  // Запускаем таймер сразу после загрузки главной формы
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Увеличиваем прогресс на 2 через каждые полсекунды
  ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 2;
  if ProgressBar1.Position = 100 then
    begin
      // После 100% прогресса останавливаем таймер
      Timer1.Enabled := False;
      ShowMessage('Timer stopped');
    end;
end;
```